# Can you use ViewBag as a datasource in an MVC 3 WebGrid?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

If so what would be the syntax.  I'm not finding much documentation and what I have is not working.

Controller Class:

```
public ActionResult Results()
    {                   

        List<GMUOverview> _results = new List<GMUOverview>
        {
            new GMUOverview { GMU = "EE00101R", UnitsIncluded = "12,13,14", SuccessRate = "19%", MinReqResPoints = "3", MinReqNResPoints="5", AvailableLicenses="123", TotalApplications=221, Season="1", Year="2009" },
            new GMUOverview { GMU = "EE00102R", UnitsIncluded = "12,13,64", SuccessRate = "19%", MinReqResPoints = "3", MinReqNResPoints="5", AvailableLicenses="123", TotalApplications=221, Season="1", Year="2009" },
            new GMUOverview { GMU = "EE00103R", UnitsIncluded = "12,43,14", SuccessRate = "21%", MinReqResPoints = "4", MinReqNResPoints="5", AvailableLicenses="123", TotalApplications=221, Season="1", Year="2009" },
            new GMUOverview { GMU = "EE00104R", UnitsIncluded = "22,13,14", SuccessRate = "22%", MinReqResPoints = "5", MinReqNResPoints="5", AvailableLicenses="123", TotalApplications=221, Season="1", Year="2009" },
            new GMUOverview { GMU = "EE00105R", UnitsIncluded = "12,13,14", SuccessRate = "33%", MinReqResPoints = "6", MinReqNResPoints="5", AvailableLicenses="123", TotalApplications=221, Season="1", Year="2009" },
            new GMUOverview { GMU = "EE00106R", UnitsIncluded = "12,13,14", SuccessRate = "44%", MinReqResPoints = "7", MinReqNResPoints="5", AvailableLicenses="123", TotalApplications=221, Season="1", Year="2009" },
        };


        ViewBag.Result = _results;        

        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{   

@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(ViewBag.Result);

      <div id="grid"> 
        @grid.GetHtml() 
    </div> 

 }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `ViewBag` instead of view models and strongly typed views? It's ugly/bad/weakly typed/crap/(put any bad word/curse you can think of here)?

And if, despite my rant you decide to use `ViewBag`, here's the correct syntax:

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(ViewBag.Result);
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{   
    <div id="grid"> 
        @grid.GetHtml() 
    </div> 
}
```

Or the correct way using view models of course:

```
public ActionResult Results()
{                   
    var _results = new List<GMUOverview>
    {
        new GMUOverview { GMU = "EE00101R", UnitsIncluded = "12,13,14", SuccessRate = "19%", MinReqResPoints = "3", MinReqNResPoints="5", AvailableLicenses="123", TotalApplications=221, Season="1", Year="2009" },
        new GMUOverview { GMU = "EE00102R", UnitsIncluded = "12,13,64", SuccessRate = "19%", MinReqResPoints = "3", MinReqNResPoints="5", AvailableLicenses="123", TotalApplications=221, Season="1", Year="2009" },
        new GMUOverview { GMU = "EE00103R", UnitsIncluded = "12,43,14", SuccessRate = "21%", MinReqResPoints = "4", MinReqNResPoints="5", AvailableLicenses="123", TotalApplications=221, Season="1", Year="2009" },
        new GMUOverview { GMU = "EE00104R", UnitsIncluded = "22,13,14", SuccessRate = "22%", MinReqResPoints = "5", MinReqNResPoints="5", AvailableLicenses="123", TotalApplications=221, Season="1", Year="2009" },
        new GMUOverview { GMU = "EE00105R", UnitsIncluded = "12,13,14", SuccessRate = "33%", MinReqResPoints = "6", MinReqNResPoints="5", AvailableLicenses="123", TotalApplications=221, Season="1", Year="2009" },
        new GMUOverview { GMU = "EE00106R", UnitsIncluded = "12,13,14", SuccessRate = "44%", MinReqResPoints = "7", MinReqNResPoints="5", AvailableLicenses="123", TotalApplications=221, Season="1", Year="2009" },
    };
    return View(_results);
}
```

and then:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<AppName.Models.GMUOverview>
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{   
    <div id="grid"> 
        @grid.GetHtml() 
    </div> 
}
```

Comment: I would like to use the ViewModel but I'm already using another model on the page and getting an error from that conflict.  If I can get past that I would not use ViewBag. Thanks!

Comment: @KeelRisk, Simply create another property for the current model to hold the Grid datasource `List<GMUOverview>`
. So you can mix the current model and the datasource. That is why View Model used. Just for your view and it will not interrupting the other data in the model.